# Should manifest.xml add include cflags for package automatically?

Tags: ros, include, manifest.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When creating a package whose header files will be included by others, we have to add the following to the manifest.xml as per to specify the package's include path.

> ```
> <export>
>    <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include" />
> </export>
> ```

Should this be done automatically as it's done for libraries?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10649/should-manifest.xml-add-include-cflags-for-package-automatically?/) by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2011-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not all packages export the same location and some don't export anything, thus we do not do it automatically.

It is our convention that we usually do the same place, but it's not required.  This is especially true for python packages etc.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1